# how can i add a rounded border with css

Tags: html, css

This only works for the top border can anyone help me??

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <body>
      <backround-color:green;
      </body>
      <div><border-radius : 15px ;></div>
      </html>
```

Comment: What you want actually.

Comment: Please go to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) first :)

Comment: You can use this http://border-radius.com/

Comment: I don't think that's even valid HTML right now...

Comment: Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) and please try to be more clear about the code... This is **totally** wrong. A `div`outside the body, unclosed tags...

Comment: Your entire code block is wrong you should give a try and learn something using [this](http://www.codecademy.com/)

Comment: That <border-radius : 15px ;> has damaged my eyes

Comment: see this link : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to sibling your element with `element`, `id` or `class`:

HTML :

```
<div class="rounded"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.rounded{
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/sq5Lmwrs/**

You can also use border-radius left, right, top and bottom : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Also you can use this link for generate what you want http://border-radius.com

Comment: how can i increase the width of the border when it is in "groove"

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>div { border-radius:15px; border:1px solid black; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This div has rounded corners.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```